# Angular2 : ¿Como crear webBuilder (template) con drag and drop?

Tags: angularjs-2.0, angular2-template

Estoy interesado en crear un web builder (template) con drag and drop desde un admin, ¿conocéis alguna libreria que me pueda ayudar?.

La finalidad es poder construir componentes "drageables" desde dicho admin y poder publicarlos en portada para así tener una portada dinámica y personalizable, he visto que está la librería de dragular, pero quería saber si conoceis alguna más o algún sistema que me ayude a lograr dicho objetivo.

Comment: ¿Ya solucionaste el problema?

Answer (score 1):

Buenas Ignacio, te dejo una librería que te puede ayudar, cuenta con una demo también:

[Librería ng2-dnd-master](http://angularjs.jqueryrain.com/angular-2-drag-drop-module/)

[Demo](http://www.jqueryrain.com/?R5yPilti)

[angularjs-2.0](/questions/tagged/angularjs-2.0) [angular2-template](/questions/tagged/angular2-template)

Comment: Muchas gracias :)

Comment: @IgnacioRom sí resolvió tu pregunta, marca como su respuesta como solución